# move xml file from one folder to other based upon file size

Tags: batch-file

I want to move xml file from one folder to another using batch script. My script already works and moves the file from one folder to another. Now I want to add logic to the Move file so that it moves only when the file size is greater that 50 bytes.
I am doing the following:
move %1\Product_*.xml /MIN:50  %1\Folder

Thankful in advance for any help

Comment: there is no `/min` or anything like that with `move`. You have to do it on your own, like `for %%i in (*.xml) do if %%~zi gtr 50 move %%i`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. Your comment is helpful as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SET /A FileSize=50

    SET Filter=*.*

    SET Folder=C:\MyFolder

    FOR /R "%Folder%" %%F IN (%Filter%) DO (
    IF %%~zF GTR %FileSize% (
    ..do staff"))
    EXIT /B /0
```